# Make required property accept null, but not undefined with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'd like to accept objects and null ([Vue.js checks for null values](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/83ea0da4b0d39ea97dab8059a7442610f116e4b5/src/shared/util.js#L41) for objects, even though `typeof null === 'object'`) in one of my components, but I want to make the validation fail for `undefined` values.

What I have tried (using [`vue-property-decorator`](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator))

```
@Prop({ required: true, type: Object, validator: v => typeof v === 'object' })
@Prop({ required: true, validator: v => typeof v === 'object' })
// I got an error:
//> Expected Object, got Null.

@Prop({ validator: v => typeof v === 'object' })
// Let's undefined through, so when I don't specify the prop, I get no warnings
// making the validator useless for my purposes
```

How can I accept objects (including `null`) as a property while making sure that the developer using my component receives a warning if the value is `undefined` (which happens when the prop is omitted)?

Answer (score 8):

From the [documentation on *props* validation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation)

> Basic type check (`null` matches any type)

After checking the source, the basic types are defined with the following regex.

> ```
> const simpleCheckRE = /^(String|Number|Boolean|Function|Symbol)$/
> ```

So `type: Object,` is incorrect. You could remove the `type` prop check, keeping the `required` and custom `validator` checks.

```
@Prop({ 
    required: true,
    validator: v => typeof v === 'object',
})
```

If you just want to ensure that the prop is at least set to null, you could just remove the `required` check and add a simple `default: null`.

```
@Prop({ 
    type: Object,
    default: null,
})
```

---

Your reference to Vue `isObject` utils is not used in the type check. It uses [`isPlainObject`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/805a4fd67602f1ac2a063284c4e2ce35be07815e/src/shared/util.js#L54-L60).

Which can distinguish `null` by doing the equivalent of:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(null)
// => "[object Null]"
```